# $('.menu[0]').attr('href').replace("t_", "f_") works on IE, but not Safari or Firefox

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, href, undefined

After reading similar questions with many variants, I'm still stuck on this issue.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
        <img class="menu" id="2"  src="./images/child/t_jamie.jpg" alt="Jamie" data-id="2" />
        <img class="menu" id="3"  src="./images/child/t_jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy" data-id="3" />
        <img class="menu" id="4"  src="./images/child/t_chloe.jpg" alt="Chloe" data-id="4" />
        <img class="menu" id="5"  src="./images/child/t_francis.jpg" alt="Francis" data-id="5" />
        <img class="menu" id="6"  src="./images/child/t_sam.jpg" alt="Sam" data-id="6" />
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$.vegas({
        src: $($('.menu')[0]).attr('href').replace("t_", "f_"),
        fade: 1500
    });
```

It works fine in IE 9, but does not work in Safari or Firefox.  Here's the Firebug error:

```
$(".menu")[0].href is undefined
```

I've tried many variants of the above, but can't get the desired functionality.  I know it has to be simple.  Can you assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant `src` instead of `href`:

```
$('.menu:first-child').attr('src').replace("t_", "f_")
```

Under certain circumstances, you will want to use `first` instead of `first-child`: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: After clearing history and cache, no luck.  I'm getting the same result as before.  Strange.